# Program not releasing handles

Tags: c#, handle, memory-profiling

I have a C# program that is doing some heavy lifting. It's creating many objects and running genetic algorithms with them.

Right now I have the issue where the program, when running at full clip (i.e. no attached debuggers or profilers) is creating ~300 handles/second. What's more, it doesn't seem to be releasing any of them. After about 15/16 hours, there are no more handles available and the program dies.

The problem I've had with debugging is that my memory management seems to be pretty good based on my profiler (JustTrace). The objects seem to be getting cleaned up (though there are a lot of Gen2 objects laying around after many hours of running), and the program seems to only take up 35MB of memory at the max. It still holds on to its handles though!

If I close the program, all the handles get released just fine.

Where should I be looking? Is there something that could be holding on to an excess of handles but not be related to the objects in memory?

Edit: Note, when I say "Handles", I mean I open up Task Manager in Windows and look at "Handles" in the "System" box on the Performance tab.

Edit2: So a couple of weeks late, I find out it's my antivirus preventing the thread handles from being released. What's strange is that the antivirus we're using shouldn't be doing this kind of process scanning according to what I've read. What's more, I don't have the ability to exclude my process from the AV scanning!

Is there something I could be doing to give the AV a chance to release the threads? I've tried adding some extra sleeps and that doesn't seem to be working. AV is BitDefender Endpoint Security 2015.

Comment: Sounds like you're not disposing of something. It's hard to tell without seeing any part of your code though... I'd expect handles to be related to files, network connections, possibly Windows graphics objects etc.

Comment: What does your program actually do? Does it open files, create threads, manipulate GDI objects...etc?

Comment: What kind of system objects do you use? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724515(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Opens files once (at startup). Originally created threads via SmarthThreadPool, now just creates tasks. No GDI manipulation to my knowledge. No graphics whatsoever, just a console app.

Comment: Oh, also doing logging using Enterprise library. Looking into the ANTS profiler right now.

Comment: Use a tool like Sysinternals Handle.exe that allows you to inspect open handles. This can give you a hint on what kind of handle you are dealing with.

Comment: You can try to use Process.GetCurrentProcess().HandleCount to discover if a particular operation leaves handles open. You would probably need a separate kind of logger for that, since the one you already using is also suspected.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to try both of those. I hadn't considered that a deadlock somewhere could be preventing finalization. I'll look into that. And I can just output to debug to "log" current process handles.

Comment: Holding on to 16+ million handles is not that simple and very hard to do by accident.  Only realistic explanation is that the finalizer thread is deadlocked.  A memory profiler is not going to show you that problem.  The debugger will, enable unmanaged code debugging and look at the call stack.  If it is not blocked on WaitForFinalizerEvent() then you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use JustTrace as well, but I had a similar problem recently where the profiler wasn't telling me the whole story.

The redgate ANTS profiler can also show you unmanaged memory which was the problem in my case. Looking at the unmanaged memory may give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my Antivirus was preventing the thread handles from being released. I haven't found a way to prevent this from happening except disabling/switching antiviruses. In the case I find a better way, I'll update here.